# Secure AJAX request to server with random port

Tags: jquery, ajax, security, ssl, restlet

I've got a Java/Restlet application that runs two servers. One at a specified port (henceforth "the UI server"), and one at a port randomly chosen at runtime (henceforth "the file server"), both at the same host.

Assume that this application is run locally, and when it is secured it is done with a self-signed certificate. The file server has CORS headers, and the UI server makes HTTP Get requests to it through jQuery AJAX.

If the application is secured with SSL, I secure both servers with the same keystore and password. However, at this point I can no longer make jQuery AJAX Get requests to the file server from the UI server. The reason is that, although the user has told their browser to make an exception for the self signed certificate in the UI server, they haven't (and indeed can't have) done so for the file server, since it has a random port. So the requests do not go through to the file server.

Basically I understand that modern browsers are going to prevent me from making an AJAX request to a server with an invalid SSL certificate, but I am creating both servers, and they're using the same certificate, and I just need to convince the browser to let me make this request

Answer (score 0):

> So the requests do not go through to the file server

I think it does, but your browser does not like the certificate being returned by the file server. Since you claim to be using the same certificate for both the UI and File server and that your browser is accepting self-signed certs, then most likely the issue is with the Common Name (CN) of the certificate being returned. If the URL to the file server is different then the CN of the certificate your browser will not like it, but because you are making a "background" AJAX call you might not see an error and it simply fails.

Comment: Ok, so "do not go through" wasn't the exact terminology I meant. Anyway, the CN on my test environment's cert actually doesn't have a URL for its CN at all (it's someone's name). I can't guarantee what my customers will have in their certificates, I need to find some way to trust the ajax request regardless of the certificate validity.

Comment: The certificate validity part is critical to the SSL Handshake, so no way totally around it. What do you mean by customer certificates - I thought this was all server certificates.  The client is the browser - correct? thus the JQuery Ajax. Perhaps terminology is being mixed up here. Try this - load a real UI Server URL into your browser and a real File Server URL into your browser - if they both load then your JQuery Ajax calls should work.

Comment: This is a web application in the sense that it runs on a customer's server and the interface lives in those customers' web browsers, but in many cases it's used entirely locally. In those cases where the customers use it on their internal network, some of them use a self-signed cert. There is no "real" UI server or File server, they're spawned by this restlet application, both running locally. And the file server is never going to be directly accessed by the user, the UI server is supposed to silently communicate with it in the background (via ajax).

Comment: As long as the certificate (self-signed or not) coming from the server is "trusted" by the customer browser, everything should be good - regardless of where the server is.  I had a similar set up in an office where we had many web servers each with a self-signed certificate. Since we had control of the certificates we created our own Certificate Authority (CA) that signed each of those server certificates. Then we configured the client browsers with that CA so every server was automatically accepted. But this is not the case for you.  Did you try that test though?

Comment: The problem is that the user tells their browser to trust the certificate on the application port (443), but since the file server comes up at a random port every time, the user can never go to that port and create an exception for the file server.

Comment: Ok, so it has an issue with the port in the file server URL - i.e. **:portnum** because it makes the URL not match the CN of the certificate. Unfortunately there is no quick/easy solution. If you could get the server certificate signed by a Certificate Authority (CA), a legit one, or your own, then browsers would just accept the server certificate regardless of the CN.  The problem with using your own CA is getting it into the customer browser.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that the browser is associating the domain name to the certificate when you choose to manually trust it.

When the a certificate is loaded from the file server (localhost), as it has a different domain name than that of the remote server, the browser does not recognise the trust already granted to it.

Possible solutions include:

- Get the user to browse to the file server first and get them to trust the certificate. Possibly each time if the browser is also associating the port number with the trust.
- Buy a certificate for "localhost" signed by a trusted CA.
- Create your own CA and use this to sign the certificates for your remote and local servers. Get the user to add this root CA to the trusted store on their machines (however you may be asking a lot as in effect you could sign the certificate of any domain with this root CA).